# How to define an initializer to fill BaseClass properties using BaseClass objects?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have two classes:

```
BaseClass : NSObject
AdvanceClass : BaseClass
```

And in AdvanceClass i have an initializer:

```
-(id)initWithBaseObject:(BaseClass *)bObj
{
    if(self = [super init]) {
        self = (AdvanceClass*)bObj;
    }

    return self;
}
```

And then when i get TRUE when i'm calling:

```
[myObject isKindOfClass:[BaseClass class]]
```

Why? I'm casting bObj to AdvanceClass object.

What i want to do here is assign all of the properties from BaseClass with properties from bObj object. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just realize that the best way is write a public method in `BaseClass` and call it from initializer. In that case you can only write this once, and it is simply to edit.

```
-(id)initWithBaseObject:(BaseClass *)bObj
{
    if(self = [super init]) {
        [self setBaseProperties:bObj];
    }

    return self;
}
```

And in BaseClass.m

```
-(void)setBaseProperties:(BaseClass*)bObj
{
    _prop1 = bObj.prop1;
    _prop2 = bObj.prop2;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

This is obvious solution, silly me.

Answer (score 2):

```
-(id)initWithBaseObject:(BaseClass *)bObj
{
    if(self = [super init]) {
        self = (AdvanceClass*)bObj; // this line of code discards the self = [super init]; and makes self a reference to a casted BaseClass object
        self.property1 = bObj.property1; // this is what you need to do for each property and remove the line with the cast
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i was sure there was easiest way that assign every properties separately. it is disappointing. Thanks, i will do that.